# How do i get amount range in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is how my table looks like

```
id | amount |     Consider table name as Amount
--------------
1  | 100
2  | 100
3  | 100
4  | 200
5  | 300
6  | 300
```

I want to write a query which returns me count of range like this:

```
amount | count
---------------
100    | 3
200    | 1
300    | 2
```

Please Help me out i am Stuck!

EDIT1 : i would like to input the amount range! Sorry i missed it!

EDIT2 : I may pass multiple ranges like 100 to 200, 200 to 300 , only 100

Comment: What is the amount range?

Comment: i would like to input the amount range! Sorry i missed it!

Comment: You have a typo,200 should be 300 last row.

Comment: The answers people provided have answered your question.  Please update your question if you're looking for something else.

Comment: @RickS Hi!! I would like to pass amount range in where condition! Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT amount,COUNT(amount)as count FROM table 
GROUP BY amount
HAVING amount BETWEEN x AND y
```

If you want groups with certain amount use `HAVING`,if you want individual rows use `WHERE amount`...

Comment: Thanks but i would like to specify the amount range! Sorry i missed it!

Comment: Thanks ! It returns me only one row when i do 
add this after "having" 

amount between 0 and 100 and amount between 100 and 500

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select amount,count(*)
from MyTable
where amount between 100 and 200
group by amount
order by amount
```

Comment: Thank you! but it return only one row no? if i have to pass range like 0-100,200-300,300-500 i cant do it ! :(

Comment: Any way i can get it for specific ranges like `only 100 to 200 and 300 to 1000` ? :)

Comment: Yes! Great It works but again Where i put or condition it displays all the list of amount between 300 to 1000;

Where as i am expecting between 300 to 1000 there are 10 entries so the count should be 10 with only one row!

Sorry if i am bothering you too much!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46369/discussion-between-user2783484-and-bws)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM Amount 
GROUP BY amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a range like this?

```
SELECT amount,COUNT(amount)as count
FROM table 
WHERE amount > 5 AND amount < 600
GROUP BY amount
```

Comment: Yes but it return only one row no? if i have to pass range like 0-100,200-300,300-500 i cant do it ! :(

Comment: This doesn't give you one row; it gives one row per amount. Sigh, using the data you gave in your example and the results you asked for this works. If there is some other data or some other results you want, you should put that in the question.

Comment: I think my question says i need the count for multiple input range! Regrets if it was miscomunication!